# How do I add a method to a ruby gem without editing the gem source?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming

I am using the `acts_as_taggable_on` gem and would like to add a method to one of the gem source files (`tag.rb`), but I do not want to change the gem source in any way.

I have tried creating my own tag.rb file to in the `/app/models` directory or in the `/lib` directory, and then adding the desired method to that file expecting that ruby will merge the two tag.rb files

But when I do I get a `NoMethodError: undefined method` ...

What am I missing?

Comment: Apologies for my uneducated answer, I clicked "delete" on it, so hopefull it will die a horrible death.

I was unaware of the possibility of reopening classes in Ruby, hence my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're right that reopening the Tag class is the way to go. I wouldn't introduce another level of inheritance unless it really made sense for your code.

I'm not sure, off the top of my head, why reopening the Tag class didn't work. A few thoughts:

1 - When you wrote your own Tag class, did it descend from ActiveRecord::Base? The Tag class in acts as taggable on does, and I could see how neglecting that might mess things up.

2 - If I needed a place to put code that reopened a plugin class for a single method, I'd probably put it in an initializer file (such as config/initializers/tag_patch.rb). Just to keep things clean.

3 - If all else fails and you still can't get the Tag class reopened properly (for whatever reason) there are other metaprogramming techniques you might try to add the method. For example:

```
Tag.send(:define_method, “method_name”) do 
  #code for your method
end
```

Comment: This seems to work.  I'm guessing your point #2 was the magic.  Getting the code into the initializers was likely what I needed (though I thought I could put my tag.rb in /lib also).

Comment: What's wrong with class_eval, seems a better and clearer way of reopening a class.

Comment: I think railsninja is right, Tag.class_eval is probably the clearest way to go. It didn't occur to me when I was writing out the define_method example.

Comment: Thanks. I added the likeness of `class Aaaa::Bbbb ; def my_method_name ; 'something to do and return' ; end ; end` to `config/initializers/appropriate_name.rb`, and *after restarting the app server* I was able to make use of my new method via `Aaaa::Bbbb.my_method_name` - (also restart `rails console` if you're using that).

Answer (score 2):

Wait, you shouldn't be adding method to the *file*, but to the *class* instead. Are you familiar with the concept of [reopening the class](http://juixe.com/techknow/index.php/2007/01/17/reopening-ruby-classes-2/)? You can't add a method just by naming your file same as the one which original class is defined in. Fortunately. :)