# Rails3: HOWTO Override/Reopen a class within a Gem and the Rails initialization process

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, overriding

My question is very similar to this one: [How do I add a method to a ruby gem without editing the gem source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788440/how-do-i-add-a-method-to-a-ruby-gem-without-editing-the-gem-source). However, this question is almost a year old and the solution that was chosen isn't the cleanest, not to me at least.

The person who provided the answer offered 3 suggestions. The first suggestion was chosen as the answer, but I would really like to figure out how to do it the second way.

I need to override an instance method of a class that is defined by a Gem. More specifically, it is the [SessionSerializer class in 1.1.2 Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/v1.1.2/lib/devise/rails/warden_compat.rb). The issue is that Devise doesn't respect non-standard primary key names. It always uses `id`. You can see that in [warden_compat.rb on Line 30](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/v1.1.2/lib/devise/rails/warden_compat.rb), it uses the following to find a model by it's ID:

```
klass.constantize.find(:first, :conditions => { :id => id })
```

In my case, the name of my `id` column is `application_user_id`, so it is obvious that this won't work. Devise has fixed this issue in 1.1.3, however, I cannot use 1.1.3 because the Devise LDAP Authenticatable plugin does not support 1.1.3.

So here's what I've done instead. I should mention first that I tested this fix by editing the Gem source directly, so now I simply want to move it into my project.

1. Created a `session_serializer.rb` file in `lib/warden/` (i.e., `lib/warden/session_serializer.rb`), reopened the `Warden::SessionSerializer` class, and redefined the `deserialize` method.
2. Modified `application.rb` to include `lib/` in `config.autoload_paths`

   ```
   config.autoload_paths += ["#{config.root}/lib"]
   ```

However, this doesn't seem to do the trick. It is still using the same code that is defined in the Gem source. So I have couple questions that I hope that can be answered:

### Questions

1. What am I doing wrong here?
2. Does Rails load files of the paths defined in `config.autoload_paths` before Gems, or is it the other way around?

Thanks for the help in advance!

### lib/warden/session_serializer.rb

```
module Warden

  class SessionSerializer
    def deserialize(keys)
      klass, id = keys

      if klass.is_a?(Class)
        raise "Devise changed how it stores objects in session. If you are seeing this message, " <<
          "you can fix it by changing one character in your cookie secret, forcing all previous " <<
          "cookies to expire, or cleaning up your database sessions if you are using a db store."
      end
      # NOTE: Original line code. Notice that it uses an :id symbol. It doesn't respect the primary key that explicity defined in the model
      # klass.constantize.find(:first, :conditions => { :id => id })
      # NOTE: THIS IS THE FIX
      klass.constantize.find(:first, :conditions => { :application_user_id => id })
    rescue NameError => e
      if e.message =~ /uninitialized constant/
        Rails.logger.debug "Trying to deserialize invalid class #{klass}"
        nil
      else
        raise
      end
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create a file called `warden.rb` in `initializers` directory and put the monkey patch code inside the file. I use this technique often in my projects to patch a gem.

To put the patch under the lib directory, do the following:

```
config.autoload_paths += ["#{config.root}/lib/warden"]
```

**PS:** I know you have tried this, but it looks like your path is not correct.

**PPS** To understand the Rails 2.3 load sequence refer to [this code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2-3-stable/railties/lib/initializer.rb#L106).

Comment: Thanks Kandada! This is my back-pocket solution. I know this will work -- it's in the original question that I linked -- but I am a bit of stickler when it comes to these things. If it turns out that what I'm trying to do can't be done, I'll give the solution to you. :)

Comment: Updated my answer take a look.

Comment: Woops, that most certainly is a typo in my autoload_paths! It is as you have it above. Let me update it.

Comment: Sorry, that is my mistake. It is just `lib`. I should explain the reasoning behind why I only specify `lib` and not `lib/warden`. I actually asked a question about Rails autoload mechanism here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018757/rails3-not-reloading-code-in-lib-while-in-development-mode. Basically, I don't have to specify `lib/warden` provided that my module/class definitions are correct. So maybe they aren't?

Comment: there is a `o` missing in `config.autload_paths`

Comment: @DanielCosta Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Have you read:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html

?

Comment: Thanks for the help! I did read this, but it didn't have anything about `config.autoload_paths`. I'll admit that my question about intialization is ambiguous, but it was more to set the stage for the follow up question: Do Gems get loaded before `lib`? Which means: When are files in `config.autoload_paths` loaded? If I apply some logic, it would seem that `lib` is loaded BEFORE Gems because I am not seeing my patch take effect. It could also be that my `config.autoload_path` is wrong, or that my `lib` layout and module/class definitions don't conform to the Rails convention to enable autoload.

Comment: Thanks for the help though. I'll update my initialization question to make it clearer.

Comment: Yes, but it appears you've settled on `autoload_paths` as the solution and are now trying to make that work. What I had hoped to convey is that there is an orderly documented way Rails initializes. You have points in that process where you are guaranteed certain levels of "safety" if you will. If you're curious what gets loaded when, just do a puts in one of your gems and in one of your initializers so you can see when they get loaded.